# The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'Object' using Hive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, hive, get, flutter-hive

I am facing this kind of issue while I'm trying to cache News from WordPress website by using Hive library, I'm getting this issue in code, The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'Object' on  " box?.get " .
It is the first time I use Hive on Flutter
How can I solve this issue?

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

const String SETTINGS_BOX = "settings";
const String API_BOX = "api_data";
///
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Color(0xFF0D47A1),
     
    ),
  );
  setupLocator();

  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(SETTINGS_BOX);
  await Hive.openBox(API_BOX);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

/// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  late final List<Article> posts;
  var data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(Hive.box(SETTINGS_BOX).get("welcome_shown"));
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box(SETTINGS_BOX).listenable(),
      builder: (context, box, child) => box?.get('welcome_shown', defaultValue: false)
          ? HomePage()
          : MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider(create: (context) => FavoriteListModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<FavoriteListModel, FavoritePageModel>(
            create: (context) => FavoritePageModel(),
            update: (context, favoritelist, favoritepage) {
              if (favoritepage == null) {
                throw ArgumentError.notNull('favoritepage');
              }
              favoritepage.favoritelist = favoritelist;
              return favoritepage;
            },
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: "/splashScreen",
          routes: {
            "/splashScreen": (_) => SplashScreen(),
            "/presentationScreens": (_) => OnboardingScreens(),
            "/homepage": (_) => HomePage(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered the box adapter?

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
Hive.registerAdapter(<YOUR ADAPTER>);
```

https://pub.dev/packages/hive/example

Comment: Yes, I just registered, but that issue doesn't go way, What can it be?

Comment: @PimpiRimpà 
Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question. I've run into this sort of problem in the past as well, but never found a solution, so I ended up switching to the Isar DB library from the same author. There I didn`t encounter similar problems. If you can't find the answer to your question, try looking at this library.